# Teamcity 5 Automatic Versioning on Build / Run

Tags: versioning, teamcity-5.0

We have the following numbering for our development

(major version).(uat release number).(qa release number).(build number)

We have three Build configurations per branch

1. Build after commit (build number++)
2. Build and push to QA (qa ++)
3. Build and push to UAT (uat ++)

The major version is set only when branching and is manual.

What I need is the Version number in Teamcity itself to change according to these rules ACROSS ALL BUILD CONFIGURATIONS.

So if the build after commit becomes 2.0.0.14 and then it is pushed to QA it becomes 2.0.1.14 and then to UAT: 2.1.1.14

Comment: Ok, I'm going to have a go at modifying the Auto-Incrementer plugin to support this